# UITextView in UITableViewCell, autocorrection can't be dismissed

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` inside a `UITableViewCell`. It's working as expected except that I can't dismiss the autocorrection suggestions that pop up. This is what my `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method looks like:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *messageCellIdentifier = @"MessageCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:messageCellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                                      reuseIdentifier:messageCellIdentifier];
    }

    // Set the background view of the cell to be transparent        
    UIView *backView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    backView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.backgroundView = backView;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    UIImage *ballonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"ChatBubbleGray.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:24 topCapHeight:15];

    NSString *text = @"Touch To Type";

    // This imageView will be the background of the UITextView
    UIImageView *balloon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:ballonImage];

    balloon.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 300, 140);

    CGRect textViewFrame;

    textViewFrame.origin.x = balloon.frame.origin.x + 10;
    textViewFrame.origin.y = balloon.frame.origin.y + 5;
    textViewFrame.size.width = balloon.frame.size.width - 12;
    textViewFrame.size.height = balloon.frame.size.height - 15;

    self.messageTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:textViewFrame];
    self.messageTextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.messageTextView.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDefault;
    self.messageTextView.editable = YES;
    self.messageTextView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    self.messageTextView.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeYes;
    self.messageTextView.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeSentences;
    self.messageTextView.delegate = self;
    self.messageTextView.text = text;
    self.messageTextView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];

    [balloon addSubview:self.messageTextView];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:balloon];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Peter Warbo: I'm suspecting following:

- By default UIImageView's userInteraction property is set to NO. Set it to YES on your ballon image view object.
  balloon.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

HTH

Comment: Gee, it was THAT simple. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: BTW, by setting userInteractionEnabled to the UIImageView. My UITableViewDelegate method `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is not triggered. How can I overcome this?

Comment: If you are trying to set ballon view as a background image for UITextView object then I would recommend following:   

 UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 140)];
 [textView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"balloon.png"]]];
    textView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10,10,0,0);    
[cell.contentView addSubView:textView];